# 2D Array of classes are null

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

Im working on a program that uses class Map that stores a 2D Array of Tile objects to form a grid. In the map class:

```
public class Map {
    private int x = 80;
    private int y = 40;
    //store the entire map - a 50x50 2d array
    private tile[][] grid = new tile[x][y];
    public void Map() {
        initialize();
        grid[0][0].tile('.');
    }

    public void initialize() {
        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x; j++) {
                grid[j][i] = new tile();
            }
        }
    }
    public void display() {
        for (int i = 0; i < y-1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < x-1; j++) {
                System.out.println("Pass [" + j + "][" + i + "]");
                System.out.print(grid[j][i].c());

            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

In the tile class:

```
public class tile {
    private String title = "null";
    private int id = 0;
    private char c = ' ';
    private boolean isVis = false;

    public tile() {
        id = 1;
        format(id);
    }

    private void format(int n) {
        c = 'A';
        title = "foo";
        isVis = false
    }

    public char c() { return c; }
}
```

When running the program, I get an output of:

```
Pass [0][0]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Map.display(Map.java:22)
   at rogue.main(rogue.java:7)
```

highlighting the line:

```
System.out.print(grid[j][i].c());
```

What I think is happening is that the class inst being initialised once created. When I just print

```
System.out.print(grid[j][i]);
```

it returns a page full of "nullnullnull" What could I do to ensure the objects are initialised properly?

Comment: Make a point of stepping through your code in your debugger before posting questions; nine times out of ten, that will answer your question. It may or may not have *this* time, but quite possibly; you would have noticed that your code in `Map` was never executed, and perhaps that would have lead you to the answer below.

Comment: I have been trying for a few hours, sorry i'm a little new to working with multiple classes. Stackexchange is always a last resort for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void Map()
```

is not a constructor (it's a regular method), so it's not invoked when you create a `Map` instance, and your `initialize` method is never called.

Change it to

```
public Map()
```

Comment: ...and ideally don't have a constructor calling an overridable method.

Comment: Damn I feel like an idiot for writing that. Thank you!